# Calling C# delegate from Python

Tags: c#, python-3.x

I am trying to call c# delegate function (updateTextBox) from python code .

Below is what I tried so far.

My .net code is:

```
namespace DynamicCS
{
    public class Test
    {
        public delegate void updateTextBoxDelegate(String textBoxString); // delegate type 
        public updateTextBoxDelegate updateTextBox; // delegate object

        public void M()
        {
            updateTextBox("Hello From delegate");
        }

        public string hello()
        {
            return "Hello from C#";
        }
    }
}
```

And my Python code is:

```
from types import *
from System import Action,EventHandler, EventArgs

sys.path.append(r'C:\\Users\\appadmin\\source\\repos\\DynamicCS\\DynamicCS\\bin\\Debug\\')
clr.AddReference(r"DynamicCS")

def updateTextBox(res):
    print(res)

from DynamicCS import Test

test = Test()
msg =  test.hello()
print(msg)
test.updateTextBox =Action[str](updateTextBox)
test.M()
```

I am getting the below error while running the python code,

```
test.updateTextBox =Action[str](updateTextBox)
TypeError: value cannot be converted to DynamicCS.Test+updateTextBoxDelegate
```

I really appreciate if anyone can point out the mistakes in my code.

Comment: If it python for .net that you are using?

Comment: Notes: you should not put `r` in-front of string and escape `\`. File path in line 4 in not portable (most OSs don't use back slash, slash should work on all/most. (File path is not portable on same OS as it may change.)

Comment: Are you using IronPython?

Comment: I am using normal python (not IronPython).  The import of dll is working fine and i am able to call hello() method of C#  from my python code as given above. My concern is to define handler of C# delegate in my python code. I have searched but so far no success on it. Any idea how to get this working.